# How can I enable Hermes engine in an updated react-native project?

Tags: android, build.gradle, react-native, react-native-hermes

I'm working on a react-native project that was originally using an old react-native version. Updating the project to use the latest react-native version, has been quite succesful in other ways. However, I have not been able to enable Hermes engine for android.

I have followed the official steps here: [Using Hermes](https://reactnative.dev/docs/hermes). To confirm if Hermes is enabled, I clean and rebuild the android project, run the app in the debug mode and use this code:

```
const isHermes = () => !!global.HermesInternal;
console.log(isHermes());
```

Also Flipper v0.80.0 cannot find Hermes app.

**android/build.gradle**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "29.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 29
        targetSdkVersion = 29
        ndkVersion = "20.1.5948944"
        supportLibVersion = "29.0.0"
        googlePlayServicesVersion = "+"
        firebaseVersion = "+"
        ext.kotlinVersion = '1.3.10'
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath('com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0')
        classpath "com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.3"
        classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlinVersion"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        mavenLocal()
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/react-native/android")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/jsc-android/dist")
        }
        maven {
            url("$rootDir/../node_modules/detox/Detox-android")
        }
        maven {
            url "https://sdks.instabug.com/nexus/repository/instabug-cp"
        }

        google()
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'https://www.jitpack.io' }

        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
    }
}
```

**android/app/build.gradle**

```
apply plugin: "com.android.application"

import com.android.build.OutputFile

project.ext.react = [
    enableHermes: true,
]

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native/react.gradle"

def enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture = false

def enableProguardInReleaseBuilds = false

def jscFlavor = 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'

apply from: "../../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/fonts.gradle"

def enableHermes = project.ext.react.get("enableHermes", true);

android {
    ndkVersion rootProject.ext.ndkVersion

    compileSdkVersion rootProject.ext.compileSdkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion
        targetSdkVersion rootProject.ext.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode 8
        versionName "2.0.0"
        testBuildType System.getProperty('testBuildType', 'debug')
        testInstrumentationRunner 'androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner'
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    splits {
        abi {
            reset()
            enable enableSeparateBuildPerCPUArchitecture
            universalApk false
            include "armeabi-v7a", "x86", "arm64-v8a", "x86_64"
        }
    }
    signingConfigs {
        debug {
            storeFile file('debug.keystore')
            storePassword 'android'
            keyAlias 'androiddebugkey'
            keyPassword 'android'
        }
        release {
            if (project.hasProperty('MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE')) {
                storeFile file(MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_FILE)
                storePassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_STORE_PASSWORD
                keyAlias MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_ALIAS
                keyPassword MYAPP_UPLOAD_KEY_PASSWORD
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        debug {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }

    applicationVariants.all { variant ->
        variant.outputs.each { output ->
            def versionCodes = ["armeabi-v7a": 1, "x86": 2, "arm64-v8a": 3, "x86_64": 4]
            def abi = output.getFilter(OutputFile.ABI)
            if (abi != null) { 
                output.versionCodeOverride =
                        defaultConfig.versionCode * 1000 + versionCodes.get(abi)
            }

        }
    }

}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  

    implementation "androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.0.0"

    implementation project(':react-native-push-notification')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.0.0'

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
      exclude group:'com.facebook.fbjni'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-network-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
        exclude group:'com.squareup.okhttp3', module:'okhttp'
    }

    debugImplementation("com.facebook.flipper:flipper-fresco-plugin:${FLIPPER_VERSION}") {
        exclude group:'com.facebook.flipper'
    }

    if (enableHermes) {
        def hermesPath = "../../node_modules/hermes-engine/android/";
        debugImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-debug.aar")
        releaseImplementation files(hermesPath + "hermes-release.aar")
    } else {
        implementation jscFlavor
    }

    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.1.0'
    implementation "com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:{{ android.firebase.messaging }}"
    implementation 'me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.21@aar'
}

task copyDownloadableDepsToLibs(type: Copy) {
    from configurations.compile
    into 'libs'
}

apply from: file("../../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesAppBuildGradle(project)
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

**package.json**

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "lint": "eslint ."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@aws-sdk/client-cognito-identity": "^3.4.0",
    "@aws-sdk/client-s3": "^3.4.0",
    "@aws-sdk/credential-provider-cognito-identity": "^3.4.0",
    "@react-native-community/async-storage": "^1.6.1",
    "@react-native-community/datetimepicker": "^3.0.9",
    "@react-native-community/masked-view": "^0.1.10",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^3.2.1",
    "@react-native-community/push-notification-ios": "^1.8.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/analytics": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^11.0.0",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^5.11.2",
    "@react-navigation/drawer": "^5.11.4",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.8.10",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.12.8",
    "acorn": "^6.1.1",
    "acorn-jsx": "^5.0.1",
    "add": "^2.0.6",
    "compare-versions": "^3.6.0",
    "instabug-reactnative": "^10.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.20",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.33",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-native": "0.64.0",
    "react-native-add-calendar-event": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-animatable": "^1.3.3",
    "react-native-app-intro-slider": "^4.0.4",
    "react-native-auth0": "^2.7.0",
    "react-native-aws3": "0.0.9",
    "react-native-elements": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^1.9.0",
    "react-native-google-places-autocomplete": "^1.3.9",
    "react-native-hyperlink": "^0.0.19",
    "react-native-image-crop-picker": "^0.35.3",
    "react-native-image-zoom-viewer": "^3.0.1",
    "react-native-in-app-notification": "^3.1.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.2",
    "react-native-keychain": "^6.2.0",
    "react-native-localize": "^2.0.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^11.4.0",
    "react-native-popup-menu": "^0.15.10",
    "react-native-push-notification": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^1.13.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.1.9",
    "react-native-screens": "^2.16.1",
    "react-native-share": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^2.10.0",
    "react-native-touchable-scale": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-windows": "^0.63.15",
    "react-redux": "^7.1.0",
    "redux": "^4.0.4",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^5.10.0",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.3.0",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "validator": "^13.5.2",
    "yarn": "^1.22.10"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.12.49",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.12.5",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.43",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "^4.11.1",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "^4.11.1",
    "babel-eslint": "^10.0.1",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.22.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.22.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "jetifier": "^1.6.4",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "^0.64.0",
    "prettier": "^2.2.1",
    "prop-types": "^15.7.2",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.1.3"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "graceful-fs": "4.2.4"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

**proguard-rules.pro**

```
-keep class com.facebook.hermes.unicode.** { *; }
-keep class com.facebook.jni.** { *; }
```

Comment: Did you run gradle clean before doing a build?

Comment: Yes, I have done it.

Comment: I am also experiencing this same issue. Did you ever find a solution?

Comment: Unfortunately not.